# laravel passport with unknown redirect_uri from Alexa App

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, redirect, laravel-passport

I have test my site with passport and can get the access_token.
(tested between two sites to verify)
With the Alexa skill it doesn't give a fixed redirect url.

It shows this:

Redirect URLs (Optional) The list of valid HTTPS redirection endpoints that could be requested during authorization to redirect the user back to after the authorization process.

Then it gives three different redirect url.

I set them all in the oauth_clients table redirect column one at a time, try all three separated with a comma, even tried to leave the field NULL, but it won't allow it to authorize. It keep bringing up a new login page.

Is there anyway not to look at the oauth_clients table for the redirect field sense it should be passed in the request?

Comment: After doing a wire shark on my website I found it just uses the first redirect.
https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/MD....
The other two maybe used depending on your location in the world.